# How to compare today's date against an array of dates

Tags: bash, scripting

I want to create an array of dates and compare it to today's date if it matches then execute test.sh file otherwise exit the loop in bash script.
I have this so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
now=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)
array=['2016-03-02','2015-01-02']
for i in "${array[@]}"
do
    if [ $now -eq $i ]; then
        bash test.sh
    else
        echo "error"
    fi
done
```

please write the correct way to do this..

Comment: Are you on the same course as this person http://serverfault.com/questions/760957/create-an-array-of-dates-in-bash-scripts-and-match-it-with-current-date ?

Answer (score 1):

- Use `declare`and braces to populate array. Elements are separated with space, not comma.
- The operator `-eq` only works with integers, which your dates aren't, use string matching.

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  now=`date +%Y-%m-%d`
  declare -a array=('date1' 'date2')
  for i in "${array[@]}"; do
    if [[ $now == $i ]]; then
          bash test.sh
    else
          echo "error"
    fi
  done
  ```

Comment: yes! its working and Thank you so much for your effort !!

Answer (score 0):

Rather than looping, you could build a space-delimited string and look to see if variable substitution changes the string:

```
today=$(date "+%Y-%m-%d")

DATES=" 2016-03-02 2015-01-02 "
if [ "${DATES/ ${today} /}" != "${DATES}" ]; then bash test.sh ; else echo "error"; fi
```

EDIT: Actually, for the purpose of this usage, the space delimiter is not essential, since the dashes implictly anchor the searches to the date format, but it is more useful generally to use a delimiter that's not within the strings being matched.