# create an array of dates in bash scripts and match it with current date

Tags: bash, scripting

Actually i want to create an array of dates and compare it to the today date if it match with the current date then execute test.sh file otherwise exit the loop in bash script. I did like this...

```
**#!/bin/bash**

cd /home/user1

current_date=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)

array=['2016-03-02','2016-03-010','2016-05-10']

for i in "${array[@]}" do

    if [ $now -eq $i ]; then

        echo "executing your bash script file"

        ./myscript.sh

    fi

done
```

when i execute above script then it gives error like `./sample.sh: line 6: [: 2016-03-02: integer expression expected`

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/760945/how-to-create-an-an-array-of-dates-in-bash-scripts

Comment: Are you on the same course as Pawan ? It seems really odd that 2 independent people would come asking essentially the same question about something that isn't particularly common.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/user1

current_date=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)

array=( 2016-03-02 2016-03-010 2016-05-10 )

for i in "${array[@]}"; do

    if [ "$current_date" == "$i" ];then

        echo "executing your bash script file";

        ./myscript.sh

    fi

done
```